# Python: Hashing a lot of large numbers

Tags: python, dataset

I've got a large data problem. My python program calculates numbers from 1 to 2^32, and I want to know if I've already calculated a number.

I could track them as a bitmap using half a gigabyte of memory. But since some numbers can be put in a bag along with others (approx 100 numbers per bag), I was wondering, if there is another way of storing my values, like hashes but less memory consuming.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: storing up to 2^32 /100 4-Byte values consumes more than 170MB of RAM if my calculations are correct. I don't like the idea of having to search more than 100MB for my values but organizing them in different lists is a huge pro.

Comment: Try to use intervals. For example, if you have computed all numbers from  `1` to `1000` and in the next iteration, you compute `800` you have juste to check if this number is in one of the intervals already computed.

Comment: @AnnZen I think that using `list` is not very efficient as complexity is `O(n)`. You can use `set` in order to reach `O(1)` in average with `in` operator.

Comment: thank you for your idea with the intervalls, but i guess it will not work out since i don't calculate the numbers in order and i have to keep track of all the intervalls until they fill up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, you can use a `set`that stores all computed numbers.
And wehn you compute a new number, you check if it's already the the set.

Let consider `compute` is the function that computes numbers

```
computedNumbers = set()   # initialize set
for i in range(1, 2**32):    # for loop
    number = compute(i)
    if number in computedNumbers:
         print("Number", number, " is already computed!")
    else:
         computedNumbers.add(number)      # add the number to the set
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: You don't need the `if` statement, `set()` will remove duplicates automatically.

Comment: @AnnZen Yes I know! Actually I added the `if` just in case he wants to `print` something or do something if the same number is computed more than once.

Comment: thank you, i just didn't think of sets because my 1 Bit values transforms into a 32Bit value. But since I use approx. 100 Bits in the bitmap approach per number, using only 32Bits per number is nice. I will try it.

Comment: @Raubsauger Don't forget to accept answer if it's OK for you.